# hive on spark, always wrong executor_cores in job application from spark master web UI

Tags: apache-spark, docker, hive

I am trying to switch `hive 2.1.1` on mapreduce to hive on spark. As told in hive on spark official site, i build a `spark 1.6.0`(as to spark rev in hive 2.1.1 source code POM) without hive. The Spark is working fine with a spark-`submit/spark-shell` test. I set the

> spark.executor.cores/spark.executor.memory

in `hive-site.xml`, also limit these 2 by

> SPARK_WORKER_CORES/SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY

in `spark-env.sh`. But after i start a hive query like `select count(*)` from hive cli, the job in spark master web UI is always with 0 CPU cores applied, so the job is not executed and hive query waits like for ever in cli. And spark cluster is set up on a docker environment on that each server is a docker container running on a server with added up to **160 cores/160g memory**. Before i set *SPARK_WORKER_CORES/SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY*, always 156 cores are applied which also leads to failure without enough resource. After i set *SPARK_WORKER_CORES/SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY* limitted to resource assigned to the docker container, 0 is applied.

i have been stuck on the problem 2 days without progress. hope some  tips from anyone who is familiar with hive on docker or run hive/spark on a docker env.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think spark execution engine works well with hive at all. The hive version you are trying integrate with spark , is [built with spark 2.0.0 and not 1.6.0](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/pom.xml#L194) There has been lot of discussion on this before . [See the thread here](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/077ee5975cf6ba8c47524e5cb0c34859d93242e8c3d935ce3a60c489@%3Cuser.hive.apache.org%3E)
You are better off with using Tez as many of of users reports on that thread.

Comment: what a pity to know, really appreciate your message still, i will try Tez instead of struggling with spark.

Comment: now i am using hive 2.1.1, which Tez rev should be used by your experience? Or by your experience, hive rev which is going well with Tex rev which?

Comment: BTW, i am not use HDP, use GNU hadoop 2.6 directly.

Comment: Its built with tez version 0.8.4 [check the pom file for hive ](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/pom.xml#L191)